# I'm trying to get a button that's in a div along with an input to save just the information in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm running into issues trying to save an input to localstorage on a button click.

I want the button to look in its own div, find the input that associated with it and save to local storage using only vanilla JavaScript.

Not necessarily looking for the answer to be handed to me but maybe a walk thru or a resource/project I can take a look at that would help. I'm still a beginner so not 100% sure what everything is called or what to look up.

```js
let times = 
    [
        {time:'5:00 a.m.', key: 1},
        {time:'6:00 a.m.', key: 2},
        {time:'7:00 a.m.', key: 3},
        {time:'8:00 a.m.', key: 4},
        {time:'9:00 a.m.', key: 5},
        {time:'10:00 a.m.', key: 6},
        {time:'11:00 a.m.', key: 7},
        {time:'12:00 p.m.', key: 8},
        {time:'1:00 p.m.', key: 9},
        {time:'2:00 p.m.', key: 10},
        {time:'3:00 p.m.', key: 11},
        {time:'4:00 p.m.', key: 12},
        {time:'5:00 p.m.', key: 13},
        {time:'6:00 p.m.', key: 14},
        {time:'7:00 p.m.', key: 15},
        {time:'8:00 p.m.', key: 16},
        {time:'9:00 p.m.', key: 17},
        {time:'10:00 p.m.', key: 18}
    ];

// mock localStorage to make this code runnable in StackOverflow
mockLocalStorage = {
  getItem: function(key) {
    const found = times.find(el => el.key === key);
  }
}

function genList() {
  for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    let newTimeBlock = document.createElement('form')
    newTimeBlock.classList.add('row', 'hour');
    newTimeBlock.setAttribute('key', times[i].key);
    document.querySelector('.dailyList').appendChild(newTimeBlock);

    //add the individual col per row
    //time Column
    let timeText = document.createElement('p');
    timeText.classList.add('col-2')
    timeText.textContent = times[i].time;
    newTimeBlock.appendChild(timeText);

    //input column
    let inputText = document.createElement('input');
    inputText.classList.add('col-9')
    inputText.style.width = '100%';
    inputText.id = 'inputs';
    // mock localStorage to make this code snippet runnable
    inputText.value = mockLocalStorage.getItem(times[i].key)
    newTimeBlock.appendChild(inputText);

    //save button column
    let saveBut = document.createElement('button')
    saveBut.classList.add('col-1', 'save');
    saveBut.textContent = 'Save';
    newTimeBlock.appendChild(saveBut);
  }
}



genList();
```

```html
<div class="dailyList"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the HTML that your code generates:

```html
<div class="dailyList">
  <form class="row hour" key="1"><p class="col-2">5:00 a.m.</p><input
    class="col-9" id="inputs" style="width: 100%;">
    <button class="col-1 save">Save</button>
  </form>
  <form class="row hour" key="2"><p class="col-2">6:00 a.m.</p><input
    class="col-9" id="inputs" style="width: 100%;">
    <button class="col-1 save">Save</button>
  </form>
  <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

A few things to correct before you continue:

1. All of your `input` elements have the same `id` attribute. This is invalid, all ids must be unique. Either delete these id attributes, or give every `input` a unique id.
2. Your `input` elements have no assigned `value` attribute, so they are showing up as 'undefined'. At the minumum, add `value=""` to each `input`.
3. Your `form` elements have a `key` attribute. `key` is an invalid attribute. if you want to set a custom attribute, you can use `data-key`, instead.

To address this:

> I want the button to look in its own div, find the input that associated with it…

Each button needs to have a click handler function. Something like this:

```js
saveBut.onclick = function (evt) {

  // get the button that was clicked
  const thisBtn = evt.currentTarget;

  // the button's associated input element is the prior sibling
  const thisInput = thisBtn.previousElementSibling;

  // get the input's value
  const val = thisInput.value;

  // etc.
  
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Its also weird that you said it came up as ClassName instead of class...when I load it into the browser it shows as class. Also changed the form to a div, removed the key attr and changed it to ids. Also the values to localStorage.getItem. Sorry if the question was worded badly. Just started not to long ago and trying to get a handle on everything.

Comment: @adumbcoder My apologies about my `className` comment. The editor I was using automatically changed all your `class` attributes to `className`. I've removed the `className` comment, above.

Answer (score 0):

Try do the following and see if it works:

```
...
saveBut.onclick = () => localStorage.setItem(times[i].key, times[i].time)
newTimeBlock.appendChild(saveBut)
```

You could take a look into this [running example](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-storage/) with the source code in [this repository](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/tree/master/web-storage). 
It's straight from this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) docs, which includes all the detailed documentation for the `Storage.getItem/setItem`.

*Also, some small tips:*

- try always using const in preference to use let
- As the localStorage always saves as pure string, you might have to convert its data using `JSON.parse(...)`